# How to Add to cart use API opencart 3.0.3.6 when the product have options

Tags: php, opencart

I'm working on a project that uses Opencart V3.0.3.6. Right now I'm working on the API.
My question is.
How to add to cart using API when the product has some variant?

I use Postman to do API testing. With the following test.

- Method : `POST`
- url : `http://domain.name/index.php?route=api/cart/add&api_token=bfbf123912381230`
- request : `product_id : 1`

But I get this error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "option": {
            "228": "Radio required!",
            "229": "Checkbox required!",
            "230": "Select required!"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add to the cart if the product has the variant to choose via API?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add option Id and option value Id in post request for required ones at least

You can post it like `option[option_id]=option_value_id`

For example

`option[228]=123`
`option[229]=456`
`option[230]=789`